# Convex hull of idempotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, idempotents

What is the convex hull of the set of $n\times n$ (potentially asymmetric) idempotent matrices?

*Apparently the powers that be want more information:*

Consider the set $S:=\{A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:A^2=A\}$, the set of idempotent matrices.  Is there a simple description of the convex hull of $S$?

By convex hull, I mean:  $C:=\{\sum_i a_i M_i:\sum_ia_i=1,a_i\geq0,M_i\in S\}$

Comment: At the very least, we know that every matrix in the hull has a trace between $0$ and $n$.  For all I know, we might get *every* matrix with trace between $0$ and $n$.

Comment: A condition on trace seems quite loose, however. Is there a smaller convex set containing the idempotent matrices?

Comment: I really don't know.  By the way, it looks like your question is about to be closed because it "needs more context".

Comment: What context does it need?  It seems like it's just a simple math question to state --- just characterizing the convex hull of $\{A:A^2=A\}.$  I'm happy to elaborate --- just thought it was nice to have a simply-stated question.

Comment: It's not me who voted for it.  It would be nice if whoever votes to close this elaborates, but that may not be the case.

Comment: I think the problem that people may have is that it looks like you didn't put enough work into answering the question yourself.

Comment: I added definitions at least.  I put a lot of thought into answering, just didn't make much progress...  If I had an answer, I wouldn't have posted the question :-)

Comment: Sure, but the people of the site and the powers that be tend to expect some kind of partial work, though not necessarily a partial result.  I happen to think your question is fine as is.

Comment: Interestingly, if we only allow for symmetric matrices, we end up with a much smaller space. In particular, we get and easy bound on the 2-norm.

Comment: True --- sets of asymmetric matrices are trickier to work with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'll do the $2 \times 2$ case.  Consider a $2 \times 2$ matrix of trace $1$:
 $$ A = \pmatrix{a & b\cr c & 1-a\cr}$$
For any real $r$, every point $(b,c)$ in the plane is a convex combination of two points on 
the hyperbola $x y = -r$ (the two axes in the case $r=0$).  Thus $A$ is a convex combination of two idempotent matrices of the form
$$ \pmatrix{ a & x\cr
   y & 1-a\cr}$$
where $xy = a-a^2$.
The only idempotent matrix of trace $0$ is $0$, and the only idempotent matrix of trace $2$ is $I$.  Any matrix of trace strictly between $0$ and $1$ is a convex combination of $0$ and a matrix of trace $1$, while any matrix of trace strictly between $1$ and $2$ is a convex combination of $I$ and a matrix of trace $1$.  Thus the convex hull in the $2 \times 2$ case consists of $0$, $I$ and all $A$ with $0 < \text{tr}(A) < 2$.

This leads to a solution in the $n \times n$ case for any $n > 2$. We have idempotent matrices of trace $1$ with the form $$\pmatrix{a & x & 0 & \ldots & 0\cr
y & 1-a & 0 & \ldots & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\cr
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\cr}$$
where $xy = a - a^2$, and convex combinations of these give all $n \times n$ matrices of trace $1$ that are $0$ outside the top left $2 \times 2$ submatrix.  By permuting indices, we get all $n \times n$ matrices of trace $1$ that are $0$ outside some principal $2 \times 2$ submatrix.
Convex combinations of these give us all $n \times n$ matrices of trace $1$.  Now any $n \times n$ matrix of trace strictly between $0$ and $1$ is a convex combination of $0$ and a matrix of trace $1$, while any matrix of
trace strictly between $1$ and $n$ is a convex combination of $I$ and
a matrix of trace $1$.  Thus we find that the convex hull 
consists of $0$, $I$ and all $A$ with $0 < \text{tr}(A) < n$.

Comment: so do we know that there won't be any matrices with trace $2$ besides $I$?

Comment: Also, what about matrices with trace $0$?

Comment: An idempotent matrix of trace $k$ is a projection on a subspace of dimension $k$.  The only subspace of dimension $2$ is the whole space, and a projection on that is the identity.  The only subspace of dimension $0$ is $\{0\}$, and a projection on that is $0$.

Comment: I see, there is a unique idempotent element with trace $2$ (or $0$), and so the convex hull must also have a unique such element.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks to both of you for your help -- it's much appreciated.  I'm surprised the convex hull is so big.

Answer (score 2):

The result can be generalized by induction. Let $C_n$ denote the convex hull over $n \times n$ matrices.

First of all, note that if $A \in C_{n-1}$ and $x \in \Bbb R^n$, then the elements
$$
\pmatrix{A&0\\0&0_{1\times 1}},E_x := \pmatrix{I_{n-1}&x\\0&0}
$$
are all in $C_n$.

Next, note that $C_n$ is closed under similarity (anything similar to an element of $C_n$ is in $C_n$).

Now, take any upper triangular $A \in C_{n-1}$.  That is,
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 & * \cdots \\
&\ddots\\
&& \lambda_{n-1}}
$$
with $\sum\lambda_i \in (0,n-1)$. Note that any convex combination of $A$ and $I$ is in $C_n$.  Also, any convex combination of a matrix $C_n$ with $E_x$ is in $C_n$.

Conclude that $C_n$ contains every upper triangular matrix with trace (strictly) between $0$ and $n$ and a non-negative bottom-right entry.  Because every matrix is upper-triangularizable, conclude that $C_n$ contains every matrix with trace strictly between $0$ and $n$.